# Joomla 2.5 custom module load only once for a session

Tags: iframe, joomla, module, preloader

I just create the iframe soundclouds player module within joomla custom html module visible on every page. The trouble is, that when I navigate my webside module player music stop every time I change menu page.

I'm wondering is there is any options for load my module only once for session or any other way?

Comment: I don't think it's anything to do with the session. Open Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools and see if there are 2 versions of jQuery being imported as they might be conflicting.

Comment: When I'm saying player music stop I don't mean the crash of the music player, but the situation that the visitor have to push play button once again and the music star to play from the begining. This situation I want to change.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean now. well obviously it will need to be played again when a new page is loaded. Im not sure how keeping it playing constantly would work but there **might** be some Ajax method